# PSCustomObject variable in If statement

Tags: powershell

I've got a variable that I am trying to define in PSCustomObject but it always errors out and will not populate the IsLicesned custom object, the UPN and Department are fine.

```
   $Report += [PSCustomObject]@{
    Upn = $ADuser.UserPrincipalName
    DEpartment = $ADUser.Department
    IsLicensed = $False}

    If ($license | where {$_.CapabilityStatus -eq "enabled"}){
    **IsLicensed** = $True}   <-- trying to define this variable
```

If I go old school it works:

```
    $CSV = "c:\2022-02-11_UPNreport.csv"

$ImportCSV = import-csv $CSV

$report = @()

foreach ($user in $ImportCSV){


    $ADUser = Invoke-Command -scriptblock {Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userprincipalname eq '$($user.UserPrincipalName)'"}
    $license = Invoke-Command -scriptblock {Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userprincipalname eq '$($user.UserPrincipalName)'" | select -ExpandProperty AssignedPlans}


    $user = New-Object psobject
    $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserPrincipalName -Value $null
    $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Department -Value $null
    $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsLicensed -Value $False


    $user.userprincipalname = $ADUser.userprincipalname
    $user.department = $ADUser.Department

        If ($license | where {$_.CapabilityStatus -eq "enabled"}){
        $user.IsLicensed = $True}

   $report += $user 

}

$Report
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the uses of `Invoke-Command` they seem to be pointless, on the other hand adding elements (`+=`) to a [fixed collection (`@()`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-6.0) is slow (exponentially slow), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708578/why-should-i-avoid-using-the-increase-assignment-operator-to-create-a-colle) for details.

```
$CSV = "c:\2022-02-11_UPNreport.csv"
$ImportCSV = Import-Csv $CSV
$report = foreach ($user in $ImportCSV.UserPrincipalName) {
    Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userprincipalname eq '$user'" |
    Select-Object UserPrincipalName, Department, @{
        Name = 'IsLicensed' # -eq  can act as a filter when LHS is Array.
        Expression = { [bool]($_.AssignedPlans.CapabilityStatus -eq 'Enabled') }
    }
}
$report
```

For the expression on the [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject), consider these examples:

- `-eq` filters the array on the Left-Hand side where the elements are equal to **Enabled**, if no element is found the result **is `$null`**:

```
'Enabled', 'Disabled' -eq 'Enabled'    # => Enabled
'Disabled', 'Disabled' -eq 'Enabled'   # => $null
```

- Any *string* that is not empty (`[string]::Empty` or `''`) when converted to *boolean* **will be `$true`**, in that sense, using the examples above:

```
[bool]('Enabled', 'Disabled' -eq 'Enabled')  # => True
[bool]('Disabled', 'Disabled' -eq 'Enabled') # => False
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your explanation makes a lot of sense adn explains why runnign this against 30k objects is taking so long.

Comment: @Chabango my pleasure, if the answer solved your doubt please consider accepting it

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation\education. Your explanation makes a lot of sense and explains why running this against 30k objects is taking so long.  For the invoke-command, the reason I am doing that is because I am running it against  a large number of objects (30 + K) in Azure\Office 365 and Microsoft recommends using the invoke-command in a  script block to help prevent timeouts on the script.

Comment: @Chabango I don't think `Invoke-Command` is needed, you can try without it and see if it works. It should.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$Report += [PSCustomObject]@{
Upn = $ADuser.UserPrincipalName
Department = $ADUser.Department
IsLicensed = $license.CapabilityStatus -contains "enabled"
}
```